# The fading of my javascript is speeding up at the end

Tags: javascript, fade

The transitioning of my text is perfect except at the end of the transition it speeds up. I need my text to continue to have the same fadein time rather than speed up.

```
$(function () {
var string = "Through education, we can all BeSafer";
var dest = $('#fadeIn');
var c = 0;
var i = setInterval(function () {
    if (c >= string.length) {
        clearInterval(i);
        dest.text(string);
    } else {
        $('<span>').text(string[c]).
        appendTo(dest).hide().fadeIn(3500);
        c += 1;
    }
}, 80);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BeSafer/r8wo2dsr/

Comment: There is no speedup. At the end of your animation you just overwrite all the content with the text, destroying animated elements before they are done.

Comment: By the way, don't use `setInterval` for animation, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: Do you know about the easing option? Maybe you want linear instead of the default, which is swing.

Comment: using promise chains (jQuery animations return promises already), you could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/nu48fqxv/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple workaround - add some spaces at the end of the sentence.

```
var string = "Through education, we can all BeSafer                         ";
```

Comment: What a nice example of what **not** to do. You need to count spaces depending on your animation speed. It will break the layout if the extraneous spaces don't fit on the same line. It will shift all the text to the left if you choose to center it. And it piles up on top of the misuse of `setInterval`, compounding the problem.